# function lines() is not working

Tags: r, plot, lines

I have a problem with the function lines.

this is what I have written so far:

```
model.ew<-lm(Empl~Wage)

summary(model.ew)

plot(Empl,Wage)

mean<-1:500 

lw<-1:500

up<-1:500

for(i in 1:500){

  mean[i]<-predict(model.ew,data.frame(Wage=i*100),interval="confidence",level=0.90)[1]

  lw[i]<-predict(model.ew,data.frame(Wage=i*100),interval="confidence",level=0.90)[2]

  up[i]<-predict(model.ew,data.frame(Wage=i*100),interval="confidence",level=0.90)[3]

}

plot(Wage,Empl)

lines(mean,type="l",col="red")

lines(up,type="l",col="blue")

lines(lw,type="l",col="blue")
```

my problem i s that no line appears on my plot and I cannot figure out why.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Whence come `Empl` and `Wage`?  Please include example data.

Comment: `predict.lm` is vectorized. No need for a `for` loop. Study the examples in `?predict.lm`.

Comment: Also, you want to pass x and y values to `lines` and not just x.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to read some introductory manuals for R. Go to this page, and select one that illustrates using R for linear regression: http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html

First we need to make some data:

```
set.seed(42)
Wage <- rnorm(100, 50)
Empl <- Wage + rnorm(100, 0)
```

Now we run your regression and plot the lines:

```
model.ew <- lm(Empl~Wage)
summary(model.ew)
plot(Empl~Wage) # Note. You had the axes flipped here
```

Your first problem was that you flipped the axes. The dependent variable (Empl) goes on the vertical axis. That is the main reason you didn't get any lines on the plot. To get the prediction lines requires no loops at all and only a single plot call using matlines():

```
xval <- seq(min(Wage), max(Wage), length.out=101)
conf <- predict(model.ew, data.frame(Wage=xval), 
    interval="confidence", level=.90)
matlines(xval, conf, col=c("red", "blue", "blue"))
```

That's all there is to it.
[image]